# Write a function that takes a list of words as a parameter and that double every word

Tags: python, string, list, function, duplicates

The list is `(['how', 'are', 'you?'])` and with the code I've pasted below, my output is `['how', 'are', 'you?']`.

So far, I have written:

```
def double_list(myList):
   a = myList
   result = []
   for words in a:
       result.append(words.split(','))
```

I know how to duplicate characters in a string, like

```
def stutter(a):
    count = ''
    for i in range (len(a)):
        count = count+ a[i] *2
    return count
```

But I'm just really having trouble doing the same thing but with words in a list instead of characters in a string.

Comment: What is the point of `words.split(',')`?  That seems to have nothing to do with your problem description. Also, `w*2` works for arbitrary strings, not just strings of length 1, so it isn't clear what your difficulty is.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not too sure, I tried to locate the elements in the list with the split function so I could then write a code that says to duplicate each element in the list. Could you suggest what I could do to find and then duplicate each word in a list when the number of words in the list is unknown?

Comment: You only need to use `split()` if the words are all collected in a string, not if they're already split into a list.

Comment: The most pythonic solution is the 1-liner `return [w*2 for w in my_list]` (which is my guess for the intended output, something that you didn't clearly specify).

Answer (score 0):

This code does do what you ask:

```
def double_list(my_list):
    result = []
    for word in my_list :
       result.append(word * 2)

    return my_list


b = double_list(['How', 'Are', 'You'])
print(b)
print(''.join(b))
```

Comment: Why are you mutating the list (in a somewhat baroque way)? OP said nothing about wanting to mutate the input list as a side effect.

Answer (score -1):

Just append each word to the `result` list twice:

```
def double_list[myList]:
    result = []
    for word in myList:
        result.append(word)
        result.append(word)
    return result
```